# Is it possible to write a type for such function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Cache function should accept a configuration object with up to ten different entities. If entity config has fields property then it should pick this fields from object.

```js
const { users, companies } = useCache({
    users: {
        ids: ['1', '2'],
    },
    companies: {
        ids: ['3', '4'],
        fields: ['title'],
    }
});

// typeof users = Record<string, User>;
// typeof companies = Record<string, Pick<Company, 'title'>>;
```

I tried to write something like this, but it works only for the first overload:

```js
type EntityMap = {
    users: User,
    companies: Company,
}

type Keys<T> = Array<keyof T>;

type PartialEntity<T extends object, TFields extends Keys<T> | undefined = undefined> = TFields extends undefined
    ? T
    : Pick<T, NonNullable<TFields>[number]>;

type EntityConfig<TName extends keyof EntityMap, TFields extends Keys<EntityMap[TName]> | undefined> = {
    [K in TName]: {
        ids: string[];
        fields?: TFields;
    }
};

type EntityResult<TName extends keyof EntityMap, TFields extends Keys<EntityMap[TName]> | undefined> = {
    [K in TName]: Record<string, PartialEntity<EntityMap[K], TFields>>;
};

interface CacheFunction {
    <TName1 extends keyof EntityMap, TFields1 extends Keys<EntityMap[TName1]>>(
        params: EntityConfig<TName1, TFields1>
    ): EntityResult<TName1, TFields1>;

    <
     TName1 extends keyof EntityMap,
     TFields1 extends Keys<EntityMap[TName1]> | undefined,
     TName2 extends keyof EntityMap,
     TFields2 extends Keys<EntityMap[TName2]> | undefined
    >(
        params: EntityConfig<TName1, TFields1> & EntityConfig<TName2, TFields2>
    ): EntityResult<TName1, TFields1> & EntityResult<TName2, TFields2>;

    // same up to 10 names
}

declare const useCache: CacheFunction;
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjglgEwC4o5hFcA7AcwG5scKBDAWwmNPOrpykaragUArswBGSOgF9MmUJCgBhAPbMwjCiFQZ6eIiTKVaOqMFzAANgI6HuPRvnyIIcOAH52Brpmmzw0AKIUpqAAsoxgWlg8UEIIiHDE8EgANMYAxipqFLjOxMqq6iCpPnLQANIQIHAAPAAqAHxaAIKIiIwg1QDWlUoAZlANdL7yAAqMiKaM5oHBHbVQEAAewBAU%20HBQSqIAVhBpwMkDAGI55usLy6vnFVV1jQA%20MWsQvZQQ%20FpCz68U741otROEDOGyWKzWGy%20%20Beb3wmAAkK4BgjiCNcGlOnVDgA5JQUbFCczmRiiSx1IEg%20oAbWEYiQAF16kNSlAZmYQMoKK8qHVsSxoGCrhtuiA%20qyguywmBDoDTudBRCoDcamzQuEqbU%20axGVBHlCYb98P9tPCqWUoJQBlqIPTiFFojwCAl9JwqFT6bYHVBXsD1u5jnK4J6oNJJMy-OLZgAlZyE4C8-kXcHnEVi1UgKUyinyy6K5XVdNSjXWnV676w41YU3my2a-m2qAxjKIfDVazUQ5jCa4KbpgsStVgM30rOB%20pM7xDSgrRC9RhpaAKecACwgRy%20%201weJN1QyFFIVv5AEYk0KoKn%20oXwoc9wfZb64CeFddKiqBxn1XXWEfGfUABQIvCahtMwzrppy3IJt%20o4Pke9QIgAlMQ6YxnAcZQRAR4wSCcFDPC1SAbewCHt%20p6KhekaStehF4ne2aPmRL63FeQ5fphpZPNCPzvKk8LwkRJEQAATIxwo9Je76ZjR%207EfeIIic%20Gz5ixxb8kJHH6txcLwv%20gHASwYHvhBuA8mxWEBrBjQAGSUaAxmmdaQnYesQnwfCSG2SAqHoWZzmPtZnneeY8ZsU5FnyROxgAPRRSQiZCBEwBKFAR4AAyCPycDeDI0JpMSThQAJsQQEuaSrnkK5rhuph4kMAnoDEcTOsV8QnpInwIKVq5-vajVIM6vWOusxBUgA5Eeo2HKNQmjSOOihghQwxSYfhii1DFoE2Sgtm2nhUIcSSIBORVxNaHX9UeY0TfSAB0TCsDQUDLQA8mUMj1X18TEOtIntWgxVdRAPXGOtdrGNETojeNk1QNNs2pF6OA%20iCUP3RAMOjQQs3GAtS2xaUa1NSJm17NtrbtvtUBohi1SHVNaOjbqsNY%20OdA-Vds13YmL1vez0O3Xw0DLXAy5KISHziAsrTbTImAfetN6ZOoOQbH9fWA8D0Sg9oiMWsNUAc1NM1zdEkgIzwGQFNkuQ64jkMG6NADMGMACzw%20DPDI-rY3BJY7um94i2YEAA)

Comment: It's probably worth preceding the question "Is it possible to write the type for such cache function?" with some natural language description of the cache function you're interested in.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3Kejm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes, your solution is nice, thank you! I will wait for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I'd take is something like this:

```
declare function useCache<T extends Params>(params: T): MyCache<T>;
```

where we'd have to define `Params` as a supertype to which all acceptable inputs to `useCache()` are assignable, and we'd also have to define a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) utility type `MyCache<T>` which transforms an input type `T` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Params` into the expected output type.

---

First you will definitely need some kind of mapping from the name of the key to the expected type.  You've already done this in your example:

```
interface EntityMap {
    users: User,
    companies: Company,
}
```

And from this we can define `Params` as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type Params = {
    [K in keyof EntityMap]?: {
        ids: EntityMap[K]["id"][],
        fields?: (keyof EntityMap[K])[]
    }
}
```

Note that this only works because each property type inside `EntityMap` has an `id` key.  Also I didn't assume that the `id` would be a `string`. Instead I use the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `EntityMap[K]["id"]` to say that whatever the `id` property is, you need to use that type in the `ids` field.

Now we can write `MyCache<T>` as follows:

```
type MyCache<T extends Params> = {
    [K in keyof EntityMap & keyof T]: Record<string,
        T[K] extends {
            fields: (infer F extends keyof EntityMap[K])[]
        } ? Pick<EntityMap[K], F> : EntityMap[K]
    > };
```

This is another mapped type, although instead of just mapping over `keyof EntityMap`, we map over the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `keyof EntityMap` and `keyof T`. That way the output type only contains those keys of `EntityMap` which are also present as keys of `T`.

The property type is `Record<string, ⋯>` (using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)) where `⋯` depends on whether or not the property `T[K]` has a `fields` entry or not.  If it doesn't, then it's just `EntityMap[K]`, the corresponding entity type. If it does, then we use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to pull out the element type `F` of the `fields` array, and [constrain it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables) to be a key of `EntityMap[K]`, and then return `Pick<EntityMap[K], F>` (using [the `Pick` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)) instead of just `EntityMap[K]`.

---

We're nearly there, but it might be a good idea to constrain `T` in `useCache()` just a bit more:

```
declare function useCache<T extends Params &
    { [K in keyof T as Exclude<K, keyof EntityMap>]: never }>(
        params: T): MyCache<T>;
```

This constraint will check if `T` has any *extra* properties other than those in `keyof EntityMap`, and if so, require them to be [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  That will discourage the use of any extra keys. Extra keys wouldn't necessarily hurt anything (although this depends on the implementation of `useCache()`, and the output of `MyCache<T>` would just ignore them, but it's arguably worthy of a compiler error.

---

Okay, let's test it out:

```
const { users: users1 } = useCache({
    users: {
        ids: ['1', '2'],
    },
});
//^? const users1: Record<string, User>
const userName = users1['1'].name; // okay

const { users: users2 } = useCache({
    users: {
        ids: ['1', '2'],
        fields: ['name', 'id']
    }
});
// const users2: Record<string, Pick<User, "id" | "name">>
users2['1'].name // okay
users2['1'].age // error
//          ~~~
// Property 'age' does not exist on type 'Pick<User, "id" | "name">'.

const { users, companies } = useCache({
    users: {
        ids: ['1', '2'],
    },
    companies: {
        ids: ['3', '4'],
        fields: ['title'],
    }
});
// const users: Record<string, User>
// const companies: Record<string, Pick<Company, "title">>
```

Looks good. The basic usage works as desired. Properties with `fields` return a `Pick` type, while those without return the full entity type.  And let's just make sure extra keys are prohibited:

```
useCache({ oops: 123 }); // error!
//         ~~~~
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

Also looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjqBLAEwC4o5hE8A7AcwG5tdKBDAWwhLIpvtyievZRKAVxYAjJPQC+mTKEhQAwgHsWYJpRCoMDHIQ7kqdXVGB5gAG0GcjPXEwIFEEOHAD8BrsZmyqwJABmTADG0ACilGagALJMYDq8wgiIcCTwSAA0JsGq6pR4LiQqahogWT7y0AAKTIiscNpYvADaANL4lFAA1hAgygFQEVEgsWAAuh4JvLiEqYOR5iNxbWPNAESEa6tjWdO4AQUWBO4kABQ9fQNDi6MrAJTNYyYyMpVQ0SCKIQAWEAA8ABUoBAAB7+SjHKA1OosOAAPkaJjaHW6vX682GoygADJUZcoACxiQAEoQHKIAh-Gw0XZ7AkrYFgiAQhpNOm8A4QI5zU5UAJIKAAMUZ4MhF3R1xiy1aYweT3ZUigbiheGCXT+kqWYBWGSFCJImtuMpMCKk9EwBDJFlq0ACwkowTMyk6SQgX2Cv0BIuZkOh9RxJnQUGRVDx6KBTAaYRBwQswktf1auvFVwWUrAcKJQggADcBVI4acTLx1DC5gC7iQPu7PQC4eacpQyBgoK6UiQ23AAIxQRVoV01iCnNk4TskEfTWYkZoAci7M91M4ATDOds9ynd6AB6LcAPWVjebna7JLJygpVMMNNgyThmEPwFbyQAcqxoP3kt3Z-OxgA6ZhsLQUA7lAyhdEwICyA+LZjk+SBwEuvbaAOPxDhOsETrwU7BnOC5QMuq60nsnLctOM4ARAeEzoQq7PJgUibpgIHQZ2S6nuSlLUtQupVKq6rpIguobAQaxQAAPlAawUWscJ3qx36rv+b7AVuoHgZB8m4X+-DQCBSCIOeTGqeyUAAH7mUZUIGZAiCgPhOkzlABDKC4QjKI+oJ4M2zqmOA0Azrxap-AJQmbOJknSXCM6-lBzrNkGna6jkJT5K5fZwYOw4mBhxYzMcZHzouK5rrwUhEVAyV5AUcyYXlcyzgAzFRAAshG5TgJH5ThURWG1pX0YxzFxY+sGkhxl5eLqAl3kNTaPpVGjVex56cVe3EqkFxR5GUkk9RAMl3pgKEemhoHKGAcxdkuDW9puKnAogBmIAAhJZ7LmRZIEAn5+EiOISCOV5bmPpGcB4NQzBiFYpjKL5CjkbmANAA)